# Moment of inertia of solid hemisphere about OZ axis with flat surface on x-y plane and origin as the centre.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, physics

To find the moment of inertia of solid hemisphere about OZ axis with flat surface on x-y plane and origin as the centre. 
Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Moment of inertia is a matrix with nine components. Do you remember the formula for each?

Comment: Do you know the moment of inertia of a full sphere about an axis passing through it's centre? You can extend it from there using symmetry arguments

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan I got your point that limit of rotational angle should be changed till pie/2 instead of pie. Is the answer half of MOI of sphere ?

Comment: $\frac{2}{5}mr^2$

Comment: Thank you. Silly mistake happened.@DhanviSreenivasan

Answer (score 0):

The mixed moments are zero because they all include a linear term in one of the two dimensions in which the hemisphere has reflectional symmetry.

The diagonal moments only contain quadratic terms, so for them the missing half doesn't affect the symmetry.

Thus all moments are just half the moments for a solid sphere of the same radius centred on the origin.